# Blocks in included files not being filled by extended templates

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a template that looks like this:

```
{% include "base/top.html" with context %}
{% include "base/nav.html" with context %}
<div id="content">
    Stuff
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% include "base/bottom.html" with context %}
```

`base/nav.html` and `base/bottom.html` contain static content, but `base/top.html` contains a `{% block title %}`. So when I have a second template as that attempts to inherit from the first file like so:

```
{% extends firstfile.html %}
{% block title %}Imarealpage!{% endblock %}
{% block content %}Lorem ipsum dorem smitshm{% endblock %}
```

The `{% block title %}` section isn't rendered. How do ensure that it, and any other blocks in included files and defined in extended templates are rendered as they should be?

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding how `{% include %}` works. The `{% include %}` tag is *not* a pre-processor; it doesn't plop the included template's code directly into the including template before rendering. Instead, `{% include %}` fires off a new independent template render of the included template (just like as if you had rendered the included template directly from your own code), and then includes the rendered *results* into the rendering of the included template.

The implication of this is that included templates have a totally separate inheritance hierarchy from their including template. You can, for instance, have a base `component.html` template with some blocks in it, and then have e.g. `foo-component.html` which starts with `{% extends "component.html" %}` and fills in some blocks from `component.html`. And then you can have a `layout.html` that does `{% include "foo-component.html" %}`, and that will render `foo-component.html`, complete with its inheritance of `component.html`, and place the result into that spot in `layout.html`. But there is zero relationship between any blocks in `layout.html` and any blocks in `component.html` -- they are separate renders with separate block structures and inheritance hierarchies.