# Nunjucks, blocks defined within "include" partial file ignored by extend

Tags: include, extends, partials, nunjucks

Here is my use case

I have a file that pulls pieces together (holy-grail.njs) that then is extended by the actual page I want (single.njs).  Problem is that the blocks defined in included files are ignored by the actual page template.  You can see the extended sidebar text is not appearing in screenshot  `<p>Here is some additional content for the sidebar extended in</p>`

Just for grins I moved that block code from sidebar.njs to holy-grail.njs and yes it is extended by single.njs so it is indeed as I suspected.

Is the a bug?, a non-feature?  How about a work around?  Or will Jade do what I want?  I assumed that "included" files were just included as in before further processing but maybe they are processed then included?   Without being able to do this my whole groovy way of organizing my template pieces/partials and then extending/customizing the content will be a no go.

this same question was asked three years ago and no one answered
[Blocks in included files not being filled by extended templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058974/blocks-in-included-files-not-being-filled-by-extended-templates)

single.njs

```
{% extends "layouts/holy-grail.njs" %}

{% block sidebar %}
<p>Here is some additional content for the sidebar extended in</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block article %}
  {% raw %}
  {{ Hugo code here to grab the article title and content }}
  {% endraw %}
{% endblock %}
```

holy-grail.njs

```
{% set reg = "regions/" %}
{% set cmp = "components/" %}

{% include "regions/head.njs" %}
<body class='page'>
    {% include  reg + "header.njs" %}
     <div class="rollover-wrapper">
        {% include reg + "topbar.njs" %}
        <main>
        {% include reg + "sidebar.njs" %}
        <section id="content">
          {% block article %}
            {# This is where one melds in article content #}
          {% endblock %}
        </section>
          </main>
          {% include reg + "footer.njs" %}
       </div>
      {% include cmp + "javascripts.njs" %}
  </body>
```

sidebar.njs

```
<aside id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
<p> some sidebar content set in the sidebar.njs file </p>
{% block sidebar %}
  {# This is where one melds in more sidebar content #}
{% endblock %}
</aside>
```

[image: nunjucks]

Answer (score 3):

This from one of the maintainers of Nunjucks

> Your guess is correct: includes operate at a "higher level" than
>   template inheritance. So an included template can have blocks, and can
>   have its own "extends" tag, and a totally separate template
>   inheritance hierarchy, but its blocks don't in any way interact with
>   the blocks of the including template's inheritance hierarchy.

So the solution I came up with is to use another tool (gulp plugin) to pre-assemble the partials then run them through nunjucks like this.

N.B my preprocessor file uses extension *.pnjs and outputs to a corresponding *.njs file which then is processed/extended in the single.njs.

```
var merge = require('gulp-file-include')
var rename = require("gulp-rename");

gulp.task('html:pre', function() {

  gulp.src(['assets/html/nunjucks/layouts/*.pnjs'])
    .pipe(merge({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: 'assets/html/nunjucks'
    }))
    .pipe(rename({extname: ".njs"}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/html/nunjucks/layouts/'));
});

var nunjucks = require('gulp-nunjucks-render');

    gulp.task('html:njs',['html:pre'], function() {

    gulp.src('assets/html/nunjucks/*.njs')
        .pipe(nunjucks({ path: ['assets/html/nunjucks'] // String or Array
    }))
            .on('error', console.log)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./builds/dev/'));
});
```

and then you'd have to change your include syntax to that supported by [gulp-file-include](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include)

like this.

```
@@include('regions/head.njs')
<body class='page'>
    @@include('regions/header.njs')
    <div class="rollover-wrapper">
        @@include('regions/topbar.njs')
        <main>
        @@include('regions/sidebar.njs')
        <section id="content">
          {% block article %}
            {# This is where one melds in article content #}
          {% endblock %}
        </section>
          </main>
          @@include('regions/footer.njs')
       </div>
      @@include('components/javascripts.njs')
  </body>
```